# Запятая перед "или"

Tags: пунктуация, или

"...пойдем мы куда-то(,) или нет..." — нужна ли тут запятая?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая не нужна. Слово НЕТ в данном случае - эквивалент однородного сказуемого: *пойдем или не пойдем*